# Produce same encryption result for same data in Java ME and Android?

Tags: java, android, encryption, java-me

I have to encrypte the same data in J2ME and android using AES algorithm.

But the encryption result are not same. I want to produce same output result of encrypted data.

J2ME code:

```
    public  String Encrypt(String text, String key)
        throws Exception {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
        byte[] b= key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        int len= b.length;
        if (len > keyBytes.length) len = keyBytes.length;
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes,0,keyBytes.length, "AES");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,keySpec, ivspec);

            byte[] outputBytes = new byte[100];
            byte[] inputBytes;
            inputBytes=text.getBytes("UTF-8");
        int results = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes,0,inputBytes.length,outputBytes,0);

            String str = new String(outputBytes, 0, results);

        String strMobile_No = Base64.encode(str.getBytes());
            String strresult=strMobile_No.toString();
          textField.setString(strMobile_No);
          return strresult;

        }
```

Android code :

```
    private  String Encrypt(String text, String key)
        throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
        byte[] b= key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        int len= b.length;
        if (len > keyBytes.length) len = keyBytes.length;
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,keySpec,ivSpec);

        byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        Log.v("GET Result from  final:",results.toString());
        strMobile_No = Base64.encodeToString(results, 1);

        return strMobile_No;

        }
```

J2ME produces: `85IV+rkwyE/oO6z7uvwKbw==`

Android produces: `XYMqEaliHBykRXGqV4LawA`

Can somebody help me to fix my code?

Comment: This doesn't even compile. Where is `ivspec` defined in the J2ME code? There are also terrible cryptographic mistakes which probably undermine the security of the whole thing.

Comment: ohh there is a mistake...ivspec is defined in above j2me function : private IvParameterSpec ivspec;

Comment: Fair enough... Where is `ivpsec` *initialized*?

Comment: i have initialized ivpsec..but still result are same .. :(

Comment: Wait... Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: sry im not getting you ...can you explain it plz..

Comment: What is there to explain? You wanted the results to be the same from both versions, and now they are the same?

Comment: @ntoskrnl : By this "i have initialized ivpsec..but still result are same .. :( " , he means to say he is still getting the same problem. Both the results are different.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I still think the IV is wrong. And I still haven't seen how the `ivspec` field is initialized in the J2ME version.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for encryption and decryption. For testing purpose you can use "1234567812345678" as your SecretKey.

```
public MCrypt(String SecretKey) {
    ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
    keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public byte[] encrypt(String text) throws Exception {
    if (text == null || text.length() == 0)
        throw new Exception("Empty string");
    byte[] encrypted = null;
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(padString(text).getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return encrypted;
}

private byte[] decrypt(String code) throws Exception {
    if (code == null || code.length() == 0)
        throw new Exception("Empty string");
    byte[] decrypted = null;
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
        decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return decrypted;
}

public static String bytesToHex(byte[] data) {
    if (data == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int len = data.length;
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if ((data[i] & 0xFF) < 16)
            str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i] & 0xFF);
        else
            str = str + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i] & 0xFF);
    }
    return str;
}

private static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (str.length() < 2) {
        return null;
    } else {
        int len = str.length() / 2;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(
                    str.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 16);
        }
        return buffer;
    }
}

private String padString(String source) {

    char paddingChar = ' ';
    int size = 16;
    int x = source.length() % size;
    int padLength = size - x;

    for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++) {
        source += paddingChar;
    }
    return source;
}
```

I hope you are aware of the fact that the secret key should be of 128/256 bits .